# Creating an area based hyperlink button

Tags: html, jquery-ui, button

I am trying to nest a form inside a button with the aim of turning the table itself into a clickable region. Clicking on the form itself would redirect the user to the edit details page.

I have managed to wrap the table in a button command so that it is clickable, but I'm having trouble inserting the hyperlink.

Comment: can you post what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

As requested, the code portion I'm working with:

*Edit, I've found a fix, additional code added in Italics if it will help anyone else...*

```
          <button   *onclick="javascript:window.location.href'http://www.webpagename.com'"*
                    style="width:100%; 
                    padding-top:3em;
                    Padding:0;
                    background:none;
                    border:none;
                    font-size:15px;"
                    >

              <table  clearfix 
                      style="width:100%; 
                      padding: 2px;
                      margin-top:3.2em;">
                      <tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td style="width:25%;">Daytime</td>
                                <td>01553 123456</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                 <td>Evening</td>
                                 <td>01553 123456</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                 <td>Mobile</td>
                                 <td>07729 123456</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                 <td>Email</td>
                                 <td>nik.mellough@work.co.uk</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tr>
           </table>
           </button>
```

Thanks again for your help.
Nik